# Merge a list of DataFrames on particular column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Lets say that I have 3 DataFrames inside of a list:
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]

And each DataFrame looks like this:

**df1**

```
puid  ean  color  temp  material 
1111  foob blue   12    metal
```

**df2**

```
puid  ean  color  weight
2222  bazb red    45
```

**df3**

```
puid  ean  height  length  weight
3333  booz 123     344     12
```

You will notice that there are unique column names within each. I need a way to merge these three DataFrames together so that the merged DataFrame looks like this:

**Merged DF**

```
puid  ean  color  temp  material  weight  length  height
1111  foob blue   12    metal     NaN     NaN     NaN
2222  bazb red    NaN   NaN       45      NaN     NaN
3333  booz NaN    NaN   NaN       12      344     123
```

The order of the columns is not so important; but should start with at least the puid.

I have tried using: `pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)`
but it produces only a concatenated dataframe (surprise surprise)

Also tried using: `reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'puid'), df_list)` but for some reason I am getting an empty dataframe returned and its not merging correctly (as in its keeping color_x, color_y for example).

**Any help would be great! Thanks :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `pd.concat(axis=1)` doesn't work, but `pd.concat((df1,df2,df3))` does:

```
  color   ean  height  length material  puid  temp  weight
0  blue  foob     NaN     NaN    metal  1111  12.0     NaN
0   red  bazb     NaN     NaN      NaN  2222   NaN    45.0
0   NaN  booz   123.0   344.0      NaN  3333   NaN    12.0
```

Comment: You are correct! I removed the axis=1 and it works perfectly. As I had a list of around 15 DataFrames I used a list comprehension like this: pd.concat([x for x in df_list]).

Comment: To clarify for OP, the default is `axis=0` if not specified and this is what you need. `axis=1` concatenates along columns, `axis=0` concatenates along index.

Comment: @QubitZ: `[x for x in df_list]` is the same as `df_list`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Usually for me its the simplest things that are the problem!